# Difference between P[x,y|z] and P[x|y,z]?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In conditional probability what is the difference between P[x,y|z] and P[x|y,z]? 
How are they expressed in terms of p[a|b] where a,b belongs to {x,y,z} and a is not equal to b}
Also please provide a intuitive idea.

Comment: What are $P[x,y\mid z]$ and $P[x\mid y,z]$ according to the definition that you practicize? Are we dealing with random variables $x,y,z$ or are we dealing with events $x,y,z$?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to MSE! As you may know, we pull users from all over the world and of all native tongues. Unfortunately, it is just as hard for us as for you to infer the meaning of the indicated notation if we don't have any context to reference. Could you clarify the difference between “P” and ‘p’? Could you please include the original text? If not, I'm afraid this will have to be deleted for lack of clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A,B,C$ be events of the sample space $\Omega$.

By definition of Conditional Probability,

if $P(C)\neq 0$, then

$$P(A\cap B | C) = \dfrac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(C)}$$

if $P(B\cap C)\neq 0$, then

$$ P(A|B\cap C) = \dfrac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(B\cap C)}$$

From these equations, you can immediately see that when $P(A\cap B\cap C)\neq 0$,
$$P(A\cap B | C)=P(A|B\cap C) \iff P(C) = P(B\cap C)$$

The following is **an example** where $P(C) \neq P(B\cap C)$.

Let us consider the **experiment of tossing 2 fair coins**.

For convenience, we denote $H$ as a head and $T$ as a tail.

The sample space $\Omega = \{HH,HT,TH,TT\}.$

Let $A$ be the event "$1$ head", $B$ be the event "First coin toss is a tail" and $C$ be the event "Second coin toss is a head".

$$P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(B\cap C) = \frac{1}{4}$$

$$P(C) = \frac{1}{2}$$

Using the definition of Conditional Probability, we can quickly deduce that **in this experiment**,

$$P(A\cap B|C) \neq P(A|B\cap C)$$